# Very simple branding background question : what do I reference for body background?

Tags: sharepoint-designer, branding, design

So if I wanted to simply change the background of one page (not in the master), just the body of one single page, using an image what would I reference using sharepoint designer? Also I know this is more of a css question but I am learning so I will go ahead and ask are there properties I can use to have the image selected fit the page instead of tile or whatever its called?

Is it something like .s4 or #s4? Thanks for the help as always!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The class you need to override is **'s4-ca s4-ca-dlgNoRibbon'**. This is the runtime class that comes from the corev4.css . This class contains a style with background-color set to white and background-image set to 'none'.

Try changing this class through an override by the following two approaches:-

1. Dedicated Custom Layout Page - You can create a custom layout page and assign the layout to your webpart page. Add the class overrides in the layout page. This way only the page attached to this layout will have its background content different while all other pages will refer to masterpage provided classes (corev4.css if no overrides are made at the site level).
2. Content Editor webpart : - You can use the out-of-the-box content editor web part and modify its html by editing page through the browser. Include the overrides for the class and save the page. This way your background changes remains limited only to one particular page.